# QtCreator: Central "header" for source code (copyright, author)

Tags: qt, comments, qt-creator

Is there a chance to define a central header (remark) being included in all source code files (automatically) in QtCreator?

The header shall contain just a remark with legal information, copyright, web site of the project etc.

I want to keep it in one central place in order I need to change it. If I manually add it to each `.h` / `.cpp` file, I need to change it everywhere in case I want to make adjustments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is to add a licence template (Options -> C++ -> File naming -> License template) like this:

```
/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   Copyright (C) %YEAR% by CompanyName                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 *   http://CompanyName.com                                                *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
```

Creator will prepend this file when creating a source or an header file, replacing %YEAR% with the current year (there might possibly be other place holders).

But if you want to change this notice on already existing files you will have to do by hand (it should not be hard to write a simple regex to do that).

Comment: You're right - it is not an issue to create a regex for this, or to use some other replacing tool (Notepad++). For the time being I am looking for a native QtCreator solution avoiding the workarounds. Useful information anyway, thanks.

Comment: **Windows:** Tools » Options » C++ » File naming » License template
**OSX:** "Qt Creator" » Preferences » C++ » File naming » License template

Answer (score 13):

This is just an addition to the answer by claudio. (Cant comments since I have too few reputation points)

[Other placeholders that can be used in the license file](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-how-tos.html#add-a-license-header-template-for-c-code):

```
%YEAR%: Year
%MONTH%: Month
%DAY%: Day of the month
%DATE%: Date
%USER%: User name
%FILENAME%: File name
%CLASS%: Class name (if applicable)
%$VARIABLE%: Contents of environment variable VARIABLE.
```

Comment: I've been looking for this for some time actually i gave up a month ago, really appreciate this, thank you...  oh yeah and monodevelop i think comes pre-packed with some license templates, i copied those over and use them in qtcreator, I'm not sure where they are from, though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Via Precompiled Header.

Just add to your `<project_name>.pro` file

```
PRECOMPILED_HEADER = pch.h
```

And add this file to your project.

But... It will be added automatically only to all .cpp files only.

Comment: I have created a file 'license.h' (just with comments), added PRECOMPILED_HEADER = license.h (.pro) but do not(!) see anything in the .cpp. Did I miss something?

Comment: :) It will not add lines from license.h to .cpp file - it will add license.h to #include list of that translation unit. F.e. you can #define _APP_VERSION 10 in that file and this definition will be accessible in each .cpp of the same project.

Comment: That's why I was surprised when I first read your comment. This is useful for compile settings, but copyright / legal remarks shall be visible when I open the files (so everybody can see it). This rules out this approach. Nevertheless, Thanks for your hints and efforts.